# How to call token from javascript to server?

Tags: java, web, server, token

I am getting token in UI(java script) which in the WEB-INF folder ,i need to pass the token to the server side.
How to send the token (its a variable) from java script to server side?

Comment: Are you talking about Java or Javascript ? Use the correct tag please

Answer (score 0):

You need to sent the token to the server (back end) via HTTP header.

Here is an example how to set a request header in a JQuery call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("token", authorizationToken);
  },
  url: "entities",
  data: "json=" + escape(JSON.stringify(createRequest(object)),
  processData: false,
  success: function(msg) {
    $("#results").append("The result =" + StringifyPretty(msg));
  }
});
```

Comment: through filter i need to send.please can you provide the code.